# Starling on android emulator

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, starling-framework

I'm using **flash CC + Air 3.8 for android + Flex 4.6 + starling**.
On the android side, **android 4.3 SDK api 18 + AVD for 7in WSVGA tablet** (tried both with and without "use host GPU" & "snapshot")
I publish my starling project using flash CC 'publish to emulator' to my found virtual android device which has started and is at the home screen. My app start and I get the **Context3D not available**. I have **`<renderMode>direct</renderMode>`** in the xml and in flash. Also tried to add **`<colorDepth>16</colorDepth>`** as someone suggested but didn't work.
I could find duplicates but no valid answer.

Comment: Is this a Runtime error or compile time error? Can you expand on what you're doing.  Normally you wouldn't use Flex along side Starling.

Comment: it's a stage3D error in the emulator. Flex is required to use the embedding functions in AS3.

Comment: Does that mean you're using the Flex Compiler, but not any of the Flex Framework?  That does make more sense.  What are "Embedding functions"?  Does the new ActionScript "Falcon" compiler included in Flash Builder 4.7 support them?

Comment: Embedding sprites for instance... My compile runs on my android tablet, just not in the emulator.

Comment: a Sprite is a Flash Class isn't it?  It wouldn't need to be embedded.  Do you mean a "Sprite sheet"?  Or some other graphical assets?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the actual runtime xml file instead of the -app.xml at source.  I found that for android, there could be a -android-descriptor.xml which exists where the .swf file is.  Ensure that the renderMode is set to direct in the bin/output folder, not the source.

Comment: For me <renderMode>direct</renderMode> was missing from bin-debug\*-android-descriptor.xml, I added it and it worked, thanks